# Sending multiple codes to an email depending on the quantity [PHP]

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to create a script where I can sell my key codes/licence codes to people. Right now I have figured a way for the php script to read off a text file and output it then delete the code/key in the text file.

```php
<?php
$content = file('test.txt');
echo $content[0];  
$file = "test.txt";
$line = 0;

$array = file($file);
unset($array[$line]);
$fp = fopen($file, 'w+');

foreach($array as $line) 
    fwrite($fp,$line); 

fclose($fp);
?>
```

My question is that is there a way to integrate PayPal with this and they can pick multiple quantities. So for example if they picked 5 codes in the checkout a php script would email them 5 codes and delete them from the list.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not really the best at this kind of stuff. Mind sharing a code to get me started?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, nor a replacement for learning. Make an attempt first, then ask questions when you're stuck. Perhaps your best bet is to start with the PayPal API docs.

Comment: SO is my last hope. I have searched everywhere. This is why I'm asking on SO. -edit- Is there a way to detect the buyers quantity in PHP?